# Find the ID of a MySQL row based on another field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a line in MySQL with information like the username and email address and I would like to find the id of the row based on the username field. Any ideas on how to find the id based on the username field?

Comment: this is very basic, did you try to find the answers before you asked?

Comment: @PugganSe Yes I googled it but I must of not put it in the right context, I have not really done much with SQL yet so I am still learning.

Comment: good luck whit your lerning, hope to see a bit more advanced question from you later then :-)

Comment: Nick, StackOverflow advice: Ask me first :)

Comment: @JJ56 Will do, I just didn't want to bug you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'NStorm';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very basic sql:

```
select id from your_table where username = 'foo'
```